# How to useradd with multiple parameters

Tags: linux, shell, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to use multiple parameters with the useradd command in linux, and I'm not really sure exactly what I should do??
I have tried the following:

```
useradd -b /home/ -g admin -m -p PASSWD -s USERNAME
```

Needless to say, it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me the correct syntax to get this working? Thanks, your help is always appreciated!

EDIT: I'm not getting an error message, It is just returning the flag variables followed by an ng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -s flag is for specifying the shell.

So either leave the -s flag out,

```
useradd -b /home/ -g admin -m  USERNAME
```

or specify a shell:

```
useradd -b /home/ -g admin -m -s /bin/bash USERNAME
```

PS. Don't specify the password on the command line. It would be visible to other users listing the processes. Moreover, specifying the password this way requires you to enter the *encrypted* password.

Comment: I tried useradd -b /home/ -g admin -m -p PASSWD -s /bin/bash USERNAME ... didn't work.

Comment: @b.j.g: Please update your question to include what error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

hmmmm maybe the MAN page: [useradd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd)

Comment: You really think I'd ask such a question without reading the man page?

Comment: @b.j.g If you did read it and misunderstood it, then maybe you could re-read it and figure out what pieces you misunderstood?